# Unable to check for non-existent field in object in angular 4

Tags: angular

I have an angular 4 application where I'm trying to insert a parameter if it exists. But I keep getting the message:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'item' of null

The object I'm working with essentially is:

```
contact: {
    shared: {
        item: string,
        _id: string
    }
}
```

Here is how I'm checking to see if the 'item' value exists:

```
this.contact.shared.linkedin.item !== null ? this.share.linkedin = this.contact.shared.linkedin : null;
```

The problem is when it returns without the 'item', like this:

```
contact: {
    shared: {
        _id: YYUIDIODU989S9FSO8F0O8SDF09
    }
}
```

I then get the error:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'item' of null

I've tried numerous ways to check for this, but nothing works. I've checked to see if the value is null, undefined, etc.

What am I doing wrong here???

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error occurred because of linkedin, not item.

check if this.contact.shared.linkedin is null.